# Audio Service Not Starting/Functioning Properly

Tags: windows, audio, service, windows-10

My Audio Service refuses to function properly. I have tried so many different solutions I can't even recall all of them.

Here's how it started; I got home from work one day to see my computer has no video signal but is turned on and receiving input from my mouse/keyboard. I force restart my computer and, after it boots up, I see that the Windows Audio Service is stopped.

I first try to use the task manager to start the service (Audiosrv) and it would blink at Starting then immediately go back to Stopped. From here I went to the Services window and tried starting it from there (Windows Audio) and, after trying to start, says Access Denied (Error 0x80070005).

So after searching a solution I went into regedit and was told to add System as a permission group for AudioSrv and the AudioEndpointBreaker service. Turns out they were already there with FULL CONTROL for both.

I try to change the logon to use Local System Account (WITH INTERACT DESKTOP CHECKED!) and voila, my audio service is running! But my bad luck continues.

None of my speakers/headphones are creating sound even though the service turned on and I can see all my devices. As an attempt I tried to do test sound, and this error appears.

[image]

Keep in mind I've restarted after every one of these fixes, both the service and my computer afterwards. As a final attempt I tried to open the Command Prompt as administrator and entered `sfc /scannow` . After verifying, this message appears.

[image]

I honestly have no clue what could've happened while I was working, but I'd rather not have to reinstall my windows to lose all my files.

## Recap of my attempts to solve

1. Start the Audiosrv service from Task Manager (failed to start but keep in mind the EndpointBreaker service was running)
2. Opened services window and tried starting the Windows Audio service (Access Denied [Error 0x80070005])
3. Tried adding System as permission group for AudioSrv and AudioEndpointBreaker to find out both already had Administrators, my user, and System with full Control.
4. Changed login to local system account with interact desktop control checked and it fixed! Supposedly. **THIS WAS THE FIX FOR 99% OF PEOPLE ON THE FORUMS**
5. After realizing my sound wasn't playing but my devices/control was showing up, tried testing sound and received an error.
6. Last resort I did a `sfc /scannow` command and was given the response shown above.

What should and what can I do to get my audio running?

### SIDENOTE

When I drag the volume slider [which usually creates a tone with the volume adjusted], the speakers/headphones meter on the Sound window do **NOT** light up green (in other words they aren't showing sound receiving on its end)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue after doing a system restore.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Local Service in the Local Users and Groups

1. Right-click This PC or My Computer, depending on which version of Windows you have, and select Manage from the dropdown menu.
2. To the right, you will see a System Tools section. Double click Local Users and Groups, and select Groups beneath it.
3. Right-click Administrators in the list in the middle of the window, and select Add to group.. from the dropdown menu.
4. Click Add, then Advanced, and then click Find Now. Double click Local Service, and click OK. You should see NT Authority\Local Service in the list, click OK. Close the Computer Management window and reboot your device. Your problem should be solved.

Then in services.msc change logon to LOCAL SYSTEM.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont permission to run Windows Audio:

1. key windows + Services
2. search Windows Audio
3. right click settings
4. login
5. Local system account and allow the service to interact with the desktop
6. save and **run Windows Audio**

Answer (score 0):

This method worked for me for fixing my Audio Service. I had to add the "Local Service" in the "Local Users and Groups" group.

1. Right-click "This PC" or "My Computer", depending on which version of Windows you have, and select "Manage" from the dropdown menu.
2. To the right, you will see a "System Tools" section. Double click "Local Users and Groups", and select "Groups" beneath it.
3. Right-click "Administrators" in the list in the middle of the window, and select "Add to group.." from the dropdown menu.
4. Click "Add", then "Advanced", and then click "Find Now". Double click "Local Service", and click "OK". You should see "NT Authority\Local Service" in the list, click "OK".
5. Close the "Computer Management" window and reboot your device.
6. In services.msc change the logon to LOCAL SYSTEM.

Your problem should now be solved.